# Deploy Github repo to server (webspace) with SSH

Tags: git, github, ssh, deployment

I would like to update the code on my webspace with GitHub. It's a private repo. I don't need automated deployments with Webhooks and PHP. I have SSH access and Git is installed. Is there a "right" way to do this. I think just cloning the repo everytime I make an update is not the "right" way. If possible without creating a repo on my webspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As illustrated in "[Editing files in your repository](https://help.github.com/articles/editing-files-in-your-repository/)", you can edit GitHub pages directly on GitHub, without having to clone your repo locally.

[image: https://help.github.com/assets/images/help/repository/edit-file-edit-button.png]

Then you need a way for your remote server to reflect the content of that modified GitHub repo. If you have cloned the repo (once), you could make a simple `git pull`.